# Launching Windows Forms via shortcut (.lnk) causes undesirable result

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, shortcut

I am using a .txt file to save data in a Windows Forms Application. The .txt is located at the same folder as the .exe. However, if I launch the app via shortcut (let's say a desktop shortcut), the app will save the .txt file in the desktop (even though the actual .exe is located somewhere else). The code I use is:

```
var myFile = File.Create(@"data.txt");
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"data.txt", true))
{
    sw.WriteLine("I like apples.");
}
```

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer That doesn't seem to be at all what he is asking...

Comment: You either need to determine the actual location of your exe (see duplicate) and use an absolute path or change your working directory.

Comment: @Milney He isn't asking anything actually, but his problem can be solved that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click the shortcut and click the **Properties** link - You will see an option to change the **Start In:** path - this is where the programs CWD will be...

Comment: This works aswell. In my case, that field was blank. I changed it to the executable location and it works like a charm. Thanks